# Style selected list-item Material UI V5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, emotion

I am using Material V5. How do I style the selected list item? I want a borderLeft of 5px.

Something like this:

[image]

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      // light: will be calculated from palette.primary.main,
      main: colors.primary
      // dark: will be calculated from palette.primary.main,
    }
  },
  components: {
    MuiListItem: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          "&$selected": {
            borderLeft: `5px solid ${colors.primary}`
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

This is my codesandbox:

[Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/selectedlistitem-material-demo-forked-p6nqr?file=/index.tsx:207-622)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItemButton from '@material-ui/core/ListItemButton';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import InboxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Inbox';
import DraftsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Drafts';

export default function SelectedListItem() {
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = React.useState(1);

  const handleListItemClick = (
    event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>,
    index: number,
  ) => {
    setSelectedIndex(index);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: '100%', maxWidth: 360, bgcolor: 'background.paper' }}>
      <List component="nav" aria-label="main mailbox folders">
        <ListItemButton
          selected={selectedIndex === 0}
          onClick={(event) => handleListItemClick(event, 0)}
        >
          <ListItemIcon>
            <InboxIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Inbox" />
        </ListItemButton>
        <ListItemButton
          selected={selectedIndex === 1}
          onClick={(event) => handleListItemClick(event, 1)}
        >
          <ListItemIcon>
            <DraftsIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Drafts" />
        </ListItemButton>
      </List>
      <Divider />
      <List component="nav" aria-label="secondary mailbox folder">
        <ListItemButton
          selected={selectedIndex === 2}
          onClick={(event) => handleListItemClick(event, 2)}
        >
          <ListItemText primary="Trash" />
        </ListItemButton>
        <ListItemButton
          selected={selectedIndex === 3}
          onClick={(event) => handleListItemClick(event, 3)}
        >
          <ListItemText primary="Spam" />
        </ListItemButton>
      </List>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There were two issues with your overrides:

1. You are using `ListItemButton` in your code without `ListItem` which is fine, but then you need to use `MuiListItemButton` instead of `MuiListItem` for the component name in the theme.
2. You used `"&$selected"` to reference the selected state, but this should instead be `"&.Mui-selected"`.

From https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#migrate-themes-styleoverrides-to-emotion:

> Although your style overrides defined in the theme may partially work, there is an important difference on how the nested elements are styled. The $ syntax used with JSS will not work with Emotion. You need to replace those selectors with a valid class selector.

Here's what the working version looks like:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      // light: will be calculated from palette.primary.main,
      main: colors.primary
      // dark: will be calculated from palette.primary.main,
    }
  },
  components: {
    MuiListItemButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          "&.Mui-selected": {
            borderLeft: `5px solid ${colors.primary}`
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[image: Edit Selected ListItemButton styles]